# Showing that $f(z)=\sinh \pi z$ is biholomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=\sinh \pi z$ and define $U,V$ by

$U=\{z\in \mathbb C: Re(z)>0, -\frac{1}{2}<Im(z)<\frac{1}{2}\}$

$V=\{z\in \mathbb C: Re(z)>0\}$

Then, $f:U\to V$ is a biholomorphism.

So far, I've expressed $\sinh \pi z$ in terms of $e^{\pi z}$ and $e^{-\pi z}$. Clearly, $f$ is holomorphic but how can I show that it is also bijective from $U$ to $V$?

Comment: what biholomorphic?

Comment: @IrbidMath are you asking what a biholomorphism? The notation is extremely standard, so I'm not sure what you're getting at with your comment...

Comment: Regarding the question at hand, first consider the Geometry of $\exp$ and what it transforms the regions into. Then shift the stuff inside exp in both desired ways and consider the impact on the image. Finally, add the two together to figure out what points get mapped where. Alternatively, consider a fundamental region (e.g. a circle) and see how it's mapped, using (at least local) conformality of holomorphic maps.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen this is your website by any chance?

Comment: Uhh, no? MSE is owned by Stack Exchange Inc.